# Xaf how to set a ObjectKey for a navigation item based on current user

Tags: c#, web, devexpress, xaf

I have a business class called UsersInfo, which consists of User details.
When the user clicks a navigation item named "MyDetails", they should be directed to a detail view, where the user should be able to view the current logged in user's users details.

I tried the following code,

```
private void showNavigationItemController_CustomShowNavigationItem(object 
sender, CustomShowNavigationItemEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (e.ActionArguments.SelectedChoiceActionItem.Id == "MyDetails")  
        {  

            IObjectSpace objectSpace = 
Application.CreateObjectSpace(typeof(UsersInfo));  

            UsersInfo appUser = objectSpace.GetObjectByKey<UsersInfo> 
(Application.Security.UserId);  

            DetailView detailView = 
Application.CreateDetailView(objectSpace, "UsersInfo_DetailView_Copy", 
true, appUser);  
            detailView.ViewEditMode = 
DevExpress.ExpressApp.Editors.ViewEditMode.Edit;  
            e.ActionArguments.ShowViewParameters.CreatedView = detailView;  
        }  
    }
```

But, I’m getting this error,
"The ObjectKey is empty while the shortcut refers to a DetailView and there are '12' objects to show".

This error occurs because, if my table has only one row there would be no issue, it would simply display the record in a detail view.

As I have multiple records in a table, it gets confused displaying which record in the table.

So, an objectkey is required when specifying the record in the table.

I also tried to add the objectkey to the navigation item in the designer by specifying CurrentUserId(), but it doesn't help. It just hides my navigation key.
Can someone help me to resolve this error?

I am sorry, if i cannot Explain my issue to you guys clearly, with my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

So either solve it in code in your custom navigation controller

```
protected override void OnNavigationItemCreated(IModelNavigationItem item, ChoiceActionItem navigationItem)
{
        if (item.Id == "MyDetails")
            item.ObjectKey = "@CurrentUserID";

        base.OnNavigationItemCreated(item, navigationItem);
}
```

or in the navigationsection of the model:

```
<Item Id="MyDetails" ViewId="UsersInfo_DetailView_Copy" ObjectKey="@CurrentUserID" IsNewNode="True" />
```